# I have to reinstall ubuntu everyday?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Sorry if its long.

So I'm working on a company that have 2 shifts. So 2 people use the same computer everyday,(I'm on day shift and the other one who use my computer is on night shift, we share computer, but with different account). For the first month, I've been using windows10, but my superior instructed me that I have to install Ubuntu on my PC (dual boot with win10), because some python script don't work with windows (I'm a web dev), specifically os.fork, I need it.
I managed to install Ubuntu(16.04 LTS) on my PC. I create a partition (50gig) using disk management in win10, that is where I install Ubuntu.

After installing, I have to change the "boot priority" in order to use Ubuntu, when my computer boot, I press F2, I put Ubuntu on top of windows so it boots on Ubuntu (Ubuntu also ask if you want to boot on windows). So everything works properly, no error, the data is persistence, I can finally continue coding.

The problem starts the next day, when I boot my pc it is asking grub rescue, like this link

https://www.google.com/search?q=grub+rescue+on+ubuntu&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwoP6IhfbTAhUEJpQKHfiBC-8Q_AUIDCgD&biw=1920&bih=1010#imgrc=DbavuOnysEX6uM:

My Ubuntu is gone, when I press F2 and look on my "boot priority" the partition exists but the name of the partition is not Ubuntu anymore. (Windows is still there). And today, for the 4th time, my Ubuntu is gone!, its grub rescue again!

Can anyone tell me, how is this possible? Does the night shift guy who I share my computer with, possibly remove my Ubuntu everyday? or is it a computer problem, the way I installed it?

Yesterday, I try to shutdown on Ubuntu, then boot, and everything is fine (just to test if Ubuntu is removed everytime I shutdown). The only real problem is when I boot my computer the next day, Ubuntu is always gone! (Im using windows10 right now)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My guess it's most likely the other guy, and have you asked him?

Comment: Not yet, I'm sure that the other guy cannot reformat or removed my Ubuntu.

Comment: Why so sure, and if so then why include him as a likely suspect?

Comment: I'm sorry, its just a speculation. I think he is an accountant.

Comment: What happens if *you* boot into Windows and then try to boot into Ubuntu again? If the computer boots in UEFI mode, Windows can play tricks like that to you. An alternative is to install Ubuntu into an external drive, for example an SSD in a USB 3 box, and boot the computer from that box.

Comment: @sudodus its fine, when I boot from WIndows then Ubuntu. I believe on your answer that Windows can play tricks like that. I ask someone right now who works in night shift, he told me that the one who use my computer doesn't do anything on the computer. He just use it normally! So it must be a computer problem?

Comment: Yes, probably. Would it be an option to use an external drive for Ubuntu? Would the company pay for an SSD and a box? I mean, you disconnect it, when you leave, so it should not be affected, when you are absent.

Comment: It is also possible that the other guy boots halfway into Ubuntu (by mistake) and then makes a hard reboot. Such adventures would probably corrupt the file system of Ubuntu's root partition and cause the problems that you see. After that he remembers to boot into Windows (but next morning he forgets ...).

Comment: @sudodus actually when I shutdown, I reset the boot priority, making windows as top priority on boot, so the night shift guy don't have an option to choose Ubuntu. But the next morning, I peek on the boot priority, The Ubuntu partition is on top and it is not Ubuntu anymore,

Comment: Well, I think the most robust option is to boot Ubuntu from an external drive, and have it connected only when you use it.

Comment: Just a suggestion but ... speaks anything for your case against simply using a Virtual mashine to run a Ubuntu within your windows? This would make things way easier sharing the same files and so on. Ofcourse some special things sometimes don't work in a virtual mashine but in this case there should be no issues I guess

Comment: @sudodos yes, I think that is the best solution.

Comment: I agree that using a virtualized Ubuntu may be the simplest solution. That said, if you want an answer to why you're seeing the problem, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an emergency disk *before* you re-install Ubuntu and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.